# How to isolate user-uploaded Razor views in multi tenant ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, multi-tenant

Is there a way to let users upload custom Razor views in an ASP.NET MVC web application?

I have multi tenancy set up in my database, I just need a way to isolate Razor views.

Is there a way to make sure a user can't upload a Razor view that uses C# to read from another tenant's files?

Comment: Allowing users to run any server side code is a recipe for disaster. Depending on their needs, if they just need to create a static site, you could just allow them to submit markdown which you then render to HTML.

Comment: As suggested by mason, it's a bad idea, instead of that, have a dynamic UI by extending the BaseViewPage of razor to use / render section from database than uploading the view pages. Little bit more work, but worthy than security concerns